# How do I fill the screen with text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

My goal is to create a Matrix Rain effect with only JS. I tried removing the padding, margins. Then dividing `window.innerWidth` by the font size `16px`. I don't know of any efficient way of printing the text so I just used a for loop `for(i = 0; i <= sum; i++)`, but it only fills less than half the screen. I also used used the `Consolas` font so the width of every character should be `16px`.

Comment: `font-size` does not specify the width.

Comment: I'm using a fixed-width font so the width and height of each character should be `16px`. Right? Edit: Sorry, I've realised the problem. All that fixed-width means is the width of every character is the same. In this case it's about `10px`. But the question stands, so is there any way I can do this?

Comment: no, depends on the font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you specifically need it to be in the DOM, have you considered doing this in Cavnas? It will run a lot smoother than using divs with lots of characters.

Here's how I would get the window dimensions.

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var width = window.innerWidth;
});
```

Here's a quick plunkr I put together for you:
https://plnkr.co/edit/hpJVAK5F3OjMihFq3nps?p=preview

Please note the rules in CSS too.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it's not exactly what I wanted but I've thought up a cheap way. I'll just use the for loop to print `<div>`s with a width and height of `16px`. That way I can just put a single character in it and centre it.